# How to understand SOLR complex phrase queries? Where can I find full documentation of ComplexPhraseQueryParser?

Tags: solr

The very short [documentation of SOLR's ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html) tells that it is a:

> QueryParser which permits complex phrase query syntax eg "(john jon jonathan~) peters*".

1. How can I know what is the meaning of the example? I can guess that tilde means a fuzzy search (i.e. any word within edit distance of 1 from the word `jonathan`), but what does `(john jon jonathan~)` mean? Is there an implicit `OR` between these words? And what does the entire query mean? Is there and implicit `AND` between the components?
2. Where can I find documentation that lists all possible keywords and operators that I can use in a complex phrase query, and their meaning?

I searched for documentation, but found nothing. I also tried SOLR debugging functionality, but it doesn't provide any details about how a ComplexPhraseQuery is parsed.

Comment: There is some additional information here https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/other-parsers.html#complex-phrase-query-parser (not enough to answer all your questions, but hopefully it helps)